# FOSUserBundle username property inside custom class' annotation for fulltext index

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to set two columns to be with `fulltext` index but my problem here is that username is coming from the FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User and if I try to use it in the annotation below I receive the error

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException] There is no column with name
>   'name, username' on table my_table_name

because in my UserEntity I do not have a property username. It is defined in the BaseUser. Any ideas on how I can manage to do that? I manage to make it work directly altering the database table but would like to know how I can use the Doctrine approach here.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table_name", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="escape", columns={"name, username"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
 */
class UserEntity extends BaseUser
```

Here is the working MySQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_clean_db.user ADD FULLTEXT INDEX escape (username, name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think tou have a typo here `columns={"name, username"}`.

It should be 2 strings separated by comma `columns={"name", "username"}`

Comment: That was :) Thank you very much!